# Python- Most efficient way to return batches of numbers

Tags: python, dictionary, numbers, logic

**Background**

I am working on some REST JSON calls via python to get a list of users. Unfortunately, the server can only return a maximum number of 50 users at a time.
e.g.

call "[0:49]" returns the first 50 users

call "[51:99]" returns the next batch of 50 users

The server does return the total number of users therefore, i am able to write some logic to get all users with multiple rest calls.

**Problem**

I have written a very messy function that prints the data in a dictionary format:

```
    def get_all_possible_items(max_no_users):
        dict={}
        base=0
        values=max_no_users//50
        if max_no_users>49:
            dict[base]=base+49
            base+=49
        else:
            base-=1
        for i in range(values-1):
            base+=1
            dict[base]=base+49
            base+=49
        dict[base+1]=max_no_users

        print dict

    get_all_possible_items(350)
```

The output looks like:

If max_no_users is 350:

> {0: 49, 100: 149, 200: 249, 300: 349, 50: 99, 150: 199, 250: 299, 350: 350}

if max_no_users is 351:

> {0: 49, 100: 149, 200: 249, 300: 349, 50: 99, 150: 199, 250: 299, 350: 351}

Is there a better way of writing this (there must be!)?

Comment: What is the form of the data returned by the REST call? I'm thinking something like `dict.update( json.loads( REST_data))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use python's `range(start, stop, step)`. You can set `step` to be 50. ie,

```
>>> for i in range(0, max_no+1, 50):
...     print i, i+49
...
0 49
50 99
100 149
150 199
200 249
250 299
300 349
350 399
```

Then possibly have an extra `if` statement for the last number to ensure that it doesn't exceed the max number, ie.

```
>>> for i in range(0, max_no+1, 50):
...     print i, i+49 if i+49 < max_no else max_no
...
0 49
50 99
100 149
150 199
200 249
250 299
300 349
350 350
```

edit: To specifically address how you can use this, do something like this:

```
def get_all_possible_items(max_no_users):
    range_dict = {}
    for i in range(0,max_no_users+1, 50):
        if i+49 < max_no_users:
            range_dict[i] = i+49
        else:
            range_dict[i] = max_no_users
    return range_dict
```

or if you want it all in one line:

```
def get_all_possible_items(max_no_users):
    return {i:i+49 if i+49 < max_no_users else max_no_users for i in range(0, max_no_users, 50)}
```

Comment: I was writing this idea up, but it appeared first.  I will only add that you can declare an empty dict outside the loop and in the loop populate it with key = 1, and value = the i + 49 part

Comment: I figured that as long as I gave the process for getting the numbers, he can figure out the rest but yes, that is correct. I will edit.

Comment: Thank you, this is a perfect answer! I knew there was a better way around it

Comment: Just for the sake of asking ( I'd like your opinion)... Would you agree that having this all on one line would make the code less self-explanatory if another developer was to review this? At what point does sacrificing readability over speed cause problems for other devs?

Comment: @RitchieRamnial  Senior devs write concise code.  There are python methods that only go on one line... dict, list comprehension..  Python is intentionally dense or terse.  (Btw the one liner above breaks on my machine. )     https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

Comment: @RitchieRamnial, I think it comes down to who and what you are writing the code for. If you know that this is going to be reviewed or used by another dev, or this is code that will be publicly available, going for readability is almost always the better choice. That being said, just having it one line DOES NOT imply that it is faster, so it isn't really a question of readability over speed.

Comment: @Merlin, edited it, I messed up the dict comprehension syntax. Stubborn me didn't actually run the code before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:: Your results are incorrect... in your question

```
    def get_all_possible_items(users):
        return  dict([[x, min(x+49,users) ] for x in range(0,users,50)])

   # or  
   #def get_all_possible_items(users):
   #     print  dict([[x, min(x+49,users) ] for x in range(0,users,50)])


    get_all_possible_items(350)
        #{0: 49, 50: 99, 100: 149, 150: 199, 200: 249, 250: 299, 300: 349}
    get_all_possible_items(351)
        #{0: 49, 50: 99, 100: 149, 150: 199, 200: 249, 250: 299, 300: 349, 350: 351}
```